# string primary key with vapor + fluent

Tags: swift, database, backend, vapor

I would like to have a table with a string column as a primary key without having to use raw SQL syntax.

Here's my fluent "preparation":

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {    
    try database.create("roles") { roles in
        roles.id("name")
        roles.string("readable_name")
    }
}
```

According to both my tests and the docs, resulting query will be similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (`name` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, `readable_name` TEXT NOT NULL)
```

I could not, so far, find a way to have a string (TEXT, VARCHAR, ...) as a primary key without raw SQL syntax and i would like to know whether it's possible to do it or not using the fluent query builder which comes with vapor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for ID types besides INT was added in Fluent 2.

https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/fluent/model/#id-type